# Regex: How to operate "AND" kind of expression in Regex?

Tags: java, android, regex

I need to get the URL from the below 2 snippets

1. `<img src='https://aaa.s3.amazonaws.com/1523622623-aaaa.jpg' width='60' align='left' hspace='5'/>`
2. `<img src="https://aaa.s3.amazonaws.com/1523622623-aaaa.jpg" width='60' align='left' hspace='5'/>`

The snipets may look similar, but see how the URL is covered with single quote (') in the first URL and with double quote (") in the second URL. Below is my code, to extract the URL from double quote.

```
//Tryig to find images in descriptions
 String str = property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
 if (m.find()) {
    newsDataBean.setNewsImageUrl(m.group(1));
    Log.d("FeedParser", "DESCRIPTION_IMAGE: " + m.group(1));
 }
```

I can get the URL in the 1st snippet, if I change my REGEX to ("src=\'(.*?)\'"). I want the regex to extract URL from either double quote or single quote. How can I do that?

Comment: would be ```scr='blah"``` allowed?

Comment: @luksch: Yes! I believe a poorly written <src> tag can be like that too

Comment: then go with the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/49822063/2229229

Comment: It looks like you want to match a single quote OR a double quote. There is no AND here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try OR clauses in order to extract with either double or single quotes:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=('|\")(.*?)('|\")");
```

or character classes:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=['\"](.*?)['\"]");
```

The latter is the better option.

Alternatively you can also use a back-reference so that single quote matches single quote or double quote matches double quote:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=(['\"])(.*?)\\1");
```

Comment: The first code seems incorrect, I only get ' or " as output

Comment: @YohanWeerasinghe The group for extract is 2 in that case.

Comment: Awesome, yes it did work. Thanks, I will accept this as the answer